# how to load whole web-page without scrolling down in cefsharp (c# winform)?

Tags: cefsharp

I found that cefsharp only loads images when scrolling down to it.

Because I would like to save the html to a pdf, so I need to load the whole page automatically.

Is it possible?

Comment: If programmatically scrolling is allowed, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/957

Comment: Link is very old and largely outdated. Full page screenshot is quite easy see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#screenshots For a PDF you'll need to scroll the page using JavaScript before calling http://cefsharp.github.io/api/96.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_PrintToPdfAsync.htm

Comment: @amaitland Thanks, it is very helpful. I found you helped many people :)

Comment: If you are still having problems then please provide an example of the html. Are the images lazy loaded with a JavaScript library or just the standard loading attribute?

Comment: @amaitland It is so kind of you. I create a sample here, https://github.com/code667/test/blob/main/test.html. I don't know it is using js lib or loading attribut.  But I find some other way to bypass it. Thanks a lot anyway